# Как пропустить добавление пустых строк PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно пропустить строки которые содержать значение NULL. Я пытаюсь собрать прайс на основе другого Excel файла. И есть необходимость пропускать пустые строки

```
    for ($row = 5; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

            if ($row == 5) {
                continue;
            }


            $export->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, $rowData[0][2]);
            $export->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $rowData[0][3]);
     }
```

Вот именно в значение $row, $rowData[0][2]; проскакивает NULL

Comment: Так сравнивайте с `NULL` и делайте `continue`? В чем проблема?

Comment: Добавьте условие `if (isset($row,  $rowData[0][2])) {
    $export->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, $rowData[0][2]);
    $export->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $rowData[0][3]);
}` То есть, если обе эти переменные НЕ null, то выполнить действие.

Comment: @robertobadjo  оба варианта пробовал. https://ibb.co/k3ubTU получаю примерно такой результат.

Comment: @МаксимСычевский Вам надо использовать другой счетчик заместо `$row`. Добавил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = 5;
for ($row = 5; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

        if ($row == 5 || empty($rowData[0][2])) {
            continue;
        }

        $export->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $count, $rowData[0][2]);
        $export->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $count, $rowData[0][3]);
        $count++;
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно!